# How to return a vector containing the labels of the maximum

Tags: r, function

I have a 4 column array, I would like to obtain a vector containing for each row the label of the column which contained the maximum value for this row.

I can do this in loops but I would like to use matrix functions for speed.

How can I do this without programming my own lib functions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a function that does just this. If `x` is your matrix, try `max.col(x)`.

Comment: +1 - didn't know about that function. It is quite fast too, less than 0.2 seconds for a 1e7 matrix on my machine.

Comment: Yes. If you type max.col you will see that most of the code is written in C.