# R: For each row, find the column-index of the column that has the highest value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to get the index of the column that has the highest value among selected columns. When trying with `dplyr`, my attempts are not giving me the right result.

```
library(dplyr);library(magrittr)
DF1 <- data.frame(Factor1 = c(1,2,4),Factor2 = c(3,1,1),Factor3 = c(9,1,0)) %>% 
    mutate(max_ind = which.max(c(.$Factor1,.$Factor2,.$Factor3))) %>% print
          Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind
        1       1       3       9       7
        2       2       1       1       7
        3       4       1       0       7
```

Where is the mistake? Why is `dplyr` behaving this way. I should probably use `rowwise`, but that does not seem to be the [best way](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-alternatives-to-rowwise/8071) to go. Any thought of how to do this in `base`, `tidyverse` or `data.table`?

#### Edit-1 (some other attempt)

With sapply I am getting this:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Factor1 = c(1,2,4),Factor2 = c(3,1,1),Factor3 = c(9,1,0)) %>%
+   mutate(max_ind = which.max(c(Factor1,Factor2,Factor3)),
+          max_ind2 = sapply(X = ., function(x) which.max(c(x[Factor1],x[Factor2],x[Factor3])))) %>% print
  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind max_ind2
1       1       3       9       7        4
2       2       1       1       7        1
3       4       1       0       7        1
```

But here I see 4 in the first row while it should be 3.

#### Edit-2

I am also looking for a solution where we can specify the columns to be used for the comparison (`which.max`)

#### Edit-3

All of `base`, `purrr::map` and `dplyr::mutate` examples work.

```
#R>DF1 <- data.frame(Factor1 = c(1,2,4,1),Factor2 = c(3,1,1,6),Factor3 = c(9,1,0,4)) 
#R>DF1 %>% mutate(max_ind_purrr = pmap(.l = list(Factor1,Factor2,Factor3),~which.max(c(...)))) %>% print()
  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind_purrr
1       1       3       9             3
2       2       1       1             1
3       4       1       0             1
4       1       6       4             2
#R>DF1 %>% mutate(max_ind_dplyr=max.col(DF1[,1:3]))
  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind_dplyr
1       1       3       9             3
2       2       1       1             1
3       4       1       0             1
4       1       6       4             2
#R>DF1 <- transform(DF1,max_ind_base=apply(DF1[, c('Factor1','Factor2','Factor3')],1,which.max))%>% print
  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind_base
1       1       3       9            3
2       2       1       1            1
3       4       1       0            1
4       1       6       4            2
```

Comment: `DF1$max_ind <- max.col(DF1)` ?

Comment: This is not complete. I should be able to specify the columns which should be used for the comparison.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Neat, didn't know this was vectorized, I've included this in my answer.

Comment: @Stat-R You can specify if needed.

Comment: @jay.sf that's fine.

Comment: Here are some dupes that don't include dplyr or data.table though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155348/get-column-index-of-maximum-value-in-each-row-of-matrix#comment59949250_36155348

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking for row-wise comparisons to find the column index that contains the maximum value **for that row**. This is why sapply is not working as, *by default*, it will look down the columns. `which.max` also deals with vectors - in your case you don't want to return the index within each vector because that refers to the **column** vector and not the row of the data.frame.

This is basically the difference between the `max` function and the `pmax` function. A row-wise version of `which.max` is `max.col` so you could specify:

```
DF1 %>% mutate(max_ind=max.col(DF1))
```

You can then choose which columns to specify:

```
# only considering columns 1 and 2
DF1 %>% mutate(max_ind=max.col(DF1[,1:2]))
```

Comment: Although it is less to write, I strongly recommend to formulate the column names explicitly. Otherwise it could yield a hell of a mess if the order changes, e.g. in a large project.

Comment: Bear in mind that `max.col` always coerces its input to a matrix, so it's not ideal for data frames.

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could do:

```
DF1 <- transform(DF1, max_ind=apply(DF1, 1, which.max))
```

However, as wisely pointed out by *@DavidArenburg* in comments - there's actually the vectorized approach `max.col()`.

```
DF1 <- transform(DF1, max_ind=max.col(DF1))
#         Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind
# Factor1       1       3       9       3
# Factor2       2       1       1       1
# Factor3       4       1       0       1
```

To get the maximum of specified column names, just do this accordingly on a subset.

```
DF1 <- transform(DF1, max_ind_subset=max.col(DF1[c("Factor1", "Factor2")]))
#   Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind_subset
# 1       1       3       9              2
# 2       2       1       1              1
# 3       4       1       0              1
```

#### Data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Factor1 = c(1, 2, 4), Factor2 = c(3, 1, 1), Factor3 = c(9, 
1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the max ind of the column and not the row which you are calculating here - it just so happens the result is the same in both cases

Comment: @Chris Actually I am looking for the index of the column with maximum value for **every row**

Comment: @Stat-R yes, that's what I mean. I think that's what Jack's answer does but not Jay's, do you agree?

Comment: @Chris I am sorry I cannot but see that the answers are identical in both the cases.

Comment: @Stat-R, it's because your example is symmetrical. Change the it to factor1=c(1,4,2) for instance and the answers will diverge. I think you are looking for Jack's answer but I may be wrong

Comment: @Chris I was confused at first, but have noticed it now. Thank you for paying attention, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @jay.sf I was wondering how you do this when you must specify the column names.

Comment: @Chris The column names which you want to include in maximum calculation?

Comment: @jay.sf Not sure that comment was directed at me? But I agree you're edited answer does the job now +1  :)

Comment: @Stat-R The column names which you want to include in maximum calculation?

Comment: @jay.sf, I have used your answer and extended it to specify columns. See my edit-3. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `purrr::pmap`:

```
DF1 <-
  data.frame(
    Factor1 = c(1, 2, 4),
    Factor2 = c(3, 1, 1),
    Factor3 = c(9, 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  mutate(max_ind = pmap_int(list(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3), ~which.max(c(...))))
```

Output:

```
  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 max_ind
1       1       3       9       3
2       2       1       1       1
3       4       1       0       1
```